# replaceAll quotes with backslashed quotes -- Is that enough?

Tags: security, sql-injection

I'm using `replaceAll` to replace single quotes with `"\\\\'"` per a colleague's suggestion, but I'm pretty sure that's not enough to prevent all SQL injections.

I did some googling and found this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/8.1.4_et._al._Security_Release_Technical_Info

This explains it for PostgreSQL, but does the replacing not work for all SQL managers? (Like, MySQL, for example?)

Also, I think I understand how the explanation I linked works for single backslash, but does it extend to my situation where I'm using four backslashes?

Please note that I'm not very familiar with databases and how they parse input, but this is my chance to learn more! Any insight would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I've gotten some really helpful, useful answers. My next question is, what kind of input would break my implementation? That is, if you give me input and I prepend all single quotes with four backslashes, what kind of input would you give me to inject SQL code? While I am convinced that my approach is naive and wrong, maybe some examples would better teach me how easy it is to inject SQL against my "prevention".

Comment: Please also note that my colleague is not a security expert my any means. He's just a fellow programmer who's had some web programming experience before.

Comment: Why four backslashes? Why not eight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,  because what about backslashes?  for instance if you turn `'` into `\'` then the input `\'` will become `\\'` which is an unescaped single quote and a "character literal" backslash.   For mysql there is `mysql_real_escape_string()` which should exist for every platform because its in the MySQL library bindings.

But there is another problem. And that is if you have no quote marks around the data segment.  In php this looks like:
`$query="select * from user where id=".$_GET[id];`

The PoC exploit for this is very simple:  `http://localhost/vuln.php?id=sleep(10)`

Even if you do a `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id])` its still vulnerable to sqli because the attacker doesn't have to **break out** of quote marks in order to execute sql.  The best solution is Parameterized Queries.

Comment: +1 for an example. Thanks for your answer! It's making this more and more clear for me. But I still have a question: what else would you pass in so that my implementation breaks (where I append four backslashes in front of a quote)? Like, if the user input were `\\'`, would that break my implementation, too? Does that mean that any number of backslashes in the user input will result in an unescaped single quote executed by the database?

Comment: @Jay Namon That is not a good idea because instead of getting a "character literal" you get a bunch of useless backslashes,  which is data corruption.  You should put a backslash behind all backslashes and then behind single quotes and double quotes.  You should do it in that order.  If you don't do backslashes first then you'll escape your escape for backslashes.   Just out of curiosity what platform is this and why doesn't it come with an escape routine?

Comment: @Jay Namon if you are successful you should be able to read in a binary file,  like an image and insert it into the database and then select it out without corrupting the image. `mysql_real_escape_string()` will do this.

Comment: @Rook I'm trying to help out a non-profit with their new Ruby on Rails set up. So we're all newly graduated students and volunteering our time to help them build a stable website to do their work. I'm looking at it as a chance to learn about web development.

Comment: @Jay Namon if you are using mysql then you must use `dbh.escape_string()` where dbh is the mysql database handler object.  Also make sure to quote all strings,  including integers as to avoid the case in php that i posted above.  For the future you should tell people that you are using ruby when post to SO.

Comment: @Rook Well, I actually didn't really want a solution because that doesn't really teach me why what I wrote was wrong. (Again, I'm trying to learn this web development stuff on my own.) I wanted some example inputs that would break my implementation. After a little googling, I confirmed that RoR has escape capabilities, but that doesn't tell me why my implementation sucked (except that I know that it sucks) -- which is why I didn't mention it.

Comment: Continued: What I really wanted was some example inputs that would actually inject SQL even though single quotes were being prepended with four backslashes. Sorry if that was confusing. I should have mentioned it in my original post. It has been updated to reflect this request.

Comment: @Jay Namon well for testing for SQL Injection under mysql a good test is trying to execute `sleep()`.  So simply trying `sleep(10)` and this payload would work for the `$_GET[id]` example above.  A more common test is or `' and sleep(10)/*` or `" and sleep(10)/*`  for your broken escape function `\' and sleep(10)` will probably work just fine.

Comment: @Jay Namon  Another thing to better learn the rules for quotes.  Get and IDE like Eclipse or Notepad++  and it will colorize strings.  Try and have a string like `var="this is a \"test\""`

Comment: @Rook The Eclipse tip is awesome. Thanks! I hadn't thought of that... PS Thanks for being so patient. I can't imagine how much of a newb I sound!

Comment: @Jay Namon Well i'd like to say thats its because i'm so helpful.  But really you asked a very important question.  So often on SO i see people say "Just use parameterized quires duh!".  When in all reality they don't understand the rules for quote marks,  which is the root of the problem and there for a very important question.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

This is not enough, and this is not the way to go. And I can say it without even knowing anything about your data, your SQL or even anything about your application. You should never, ever include any user data directly into your SQL. You should use [parameterized statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements) instead.

Besides if you are asking this question you shouldn't write your own SQL by hand in the first place. Use a good [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) instead. Asking if your home-grown regular expression would make your application safe from SQL injection is like asking if your home-grown memory allocation routine that you have written in Assembly language is safe from buffer overruns - to which I would say: if you are asking this question then you should use a memory-safe language in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was able to read about that after some googling, but in the end, I didn't feel quite satisfied. While I know now that my implementation is naive and wrong, I feel like I'm missing some part of the picture because I can't myself think of input that would break my implementation. I've added an extra question in the post related to this. Please read and answer if you have the time!

Answer (score 1):

A simple case of SQL injection works like this (in pseudocode):

```
name = form_params["name"]
year = 2011
sql = "INSERT INTO Students (name, year) " + 
      "VALUES ('" + name + "', " + year + ");"
database_handle.query(sql)
```

`year` is supplied by you, the programmer, so it's not tainted, and can be embedded in the query in any way you find suitable; in this case — as an unquoted number.

But `name` is supplied by the user and so can be anything. Along comes [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) and inputs this value:

```
name = "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; -- "
```

And the query becomes

```
INSERT INTO Students (name, year) VALUES ('Robert');
DROP TABLE Students; -- ', 2011);
```

That substitution turned your one query into two.

The first one gives an error because of the mismatched row count, but that doesn't matter, because the database is able to unambiguously find and run the second query. The attacker can work around the error by fiddling with the input anyway. The `--` is a comment so that the rest of the input is ignored.

Note how data suddenly became code — a typical sign of a security problem.

What the suggested replacement does is this:

```
name = form_params["name"].regex_replace("'", "\\\\'")
```

How this works is confusing, hence my earlier comment. The string literal `"\\\\'"` represents the string `\\'`. The `regex_replace` function interprets that as the string `\'`. The database then sees

```
... VALUES ('Robert\'); DROP TABLE Students; -- ', 2011);
```

and interprets that correctly as a quite unusual name.

Among other problems this approach is very fragile. If the strings you use in your language don't substitute `\\` as `\`, if your string substitution function doesn't interpret `\\` as `\` (if it's not a regex function or it uses `$1` instead of `\1` for backreferences) you could end up with an even number of slashes like

```
... VALUES ('Robert\\'); DROP TABLE Students; -- ', 2011);
```

and *no* SQL injection will be prevented.

The solution is not to check what the language and library does with all possible input you can think of, or to anticipate what it might do in a future version, but rather to use the facilities provided by the database. These usually come in two flavours:

- database-aware escaping, which does exactly the right escaping of any data because the client library matches the server and it knows what the character encoding of the database you are querying is:

  `sql = "... '" + database_handle.escape(name) + "' ..."`
- out-of-band data submission (usually with prepared statments), so the data isn't even in the same string as the code:

  `sql = "... VALUES (:n, :y);"`
  `database_handle.query(sql, n = name, y = year)`

Comment: Why do people insist on doing MS-SQL specific sql injection? Whats with the query stacking?  Also the guy said he was using MySQL,  maybe you should post something a bit more on topic.

Comment: @Rook – You mean the mismatched column count? It worked on the MySQL command line when I checked, and, although, as I just discovered, it doesn't work from PHP PDO, I did suggest that the attacker could try more fields.

Comment: @aaz No, try writing a MySQL exploit.  You can't stack queries with `mysql_query()`,  postgresql,  oracle, db2 and many others are in the same boat. sqlite and ms-sql allow query stacking,  and thats it as far as I know.  "Hack-proofing MySQL" is a good paper and it talks about techniques used to leverage sql injection and how to lock down your database.

Comment: @Rook – PostgreSQL does allow it, don't know about the others. The MySQL PDO driver allows it, I guess it uses `mysqli::multi_query`. So calling it MS-SQL-specific is incorrect, though it is driver-specific.

Comment: @aaz  Cool, now name one application that uses `multi_query()`.    The whole point of writing exploit is you have to work with the application to defeat it.   Try [writing an exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/author/?a=628),  and then tell me how well query stacking works for you.

Comment: @Rook – Sure: [directly](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=%28mysqli_%7C-%3E%29multi_query%5C%28) and [indirectly](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=%5BdD%5D%5BbB%5D%5BhH%5D%3F-%3E%28exec%7Cquery%29%5C(%5Cs%2A%28%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2A%22%7C%5B%5E%28%5D%29%28%5B%5E%22,%5D%2A%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2A%22%29%2A%5B%5E%22,%5D%5C%29). Now show me one competent admin who granted the privileges for `INTO OUTFILE`. (Nice list. Although with phpMyAdmin one could have seen that coming, right?)

Comment: @aaz  Aaah yes, `into outfile` a common exploit technique found on the boards.  But to be honest your out of your element.  My point is you need to study exploit code,  like the code I write.  Instead of learning how to hack from comic books.  You should check out the OpenClassifieds chain that i wrote,  thats a solid sqli exploit that is configuration independent.

Comment: @aaz Also `into outfile` was fixed on the latest Ubuntu systems because of AppArmor,  So i bypassed AppArmor in my PHPNuke exploit :D.

Comment: @aaz,  i'm not sure what your getting at with that google search your just [proving my point](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=mysql_query&sbtn=Search).